# Пионерия — имя собственное или нарицательное?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика

***Страна пионерия (Пионерия)***. В этом словосочетании слово ***пионерия*** лучше написать с маленькой буквы или с большой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Страна Пионерия**.

В текстах встречаются разные варианты (прописная или строчная буква, наличие или отсутствие кавычек), но этот вариант наиболее удачный.

Почему?

Во-первых, есть **нарицательное существительное *пионерия*,** которое пишется со строчной буквы. Согласно словарю,  ПИОНЕРИЯ; ж. собир. Пионеры.  Сегодня праздник у ребят, Ликует **пионерия**!

Соответственно, страна Пионерия — это уже **другое, условное** значение, а условность является признаком имени собственного.

Во-вторых, **кавычки использовать не стоит**, так как условность достаточно ясна и без кавычек, а названия стран в кавычках не пишутся.

Кавычки имеют свои правила употребления:  они выполняют   различные функции, а также  используются при обозначения собственных имен **определенной тематики**. Сравнить: журнал "Юность" и  страна Юность.

Answer (score 2):

Стране (неважно какой — виртуальной, символической, игровой) дано имя. Всякое такое имя не может быть написано со строчной, даже если в его состав входит само слово *страна*. В тексте, не в начале фразы, возможен и вариант — *страна Пионерия*, где только одно именное слово.

У Юлии Друниной есть сборник стихов «Страна Юность».